# Numeric overflow error while Truncating table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
Truncate table test_abc;
```

It is giving me error :

```
Oracle error 01426: Numeric Overflow.
```

Oracle version is 11g.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Please provide a reproducible test case that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Alex Poole that it seems odd for a `TRUNCATE` to cause that error.  Perhaps there is an error with a recursive SQL or PL/SQL statement that executes with
 each truncate.  Post the *entire* error message, it should include the relevant errors, objects, and line numbers.

If that doesn't help, look for any triggers that  execute for each truncate.  There are many potentially relevant triggering events.  These are the most likely, but it's 
also possible there is an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` trigger on an X$ table or something odd.

```
select *
from dba_triggers
where triggering_event like '%DDL%' or triggering_event like '%TRUNCATE%';
```

The objects can be viewed through `DBA_SOURCE`, unless they are wrapped.